# Install tensorflow, theano, sklearn, nltk all inside miniconda2 docker container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, theano

I have pulled conda/miniconda2 image and I'm able to run it but what so ever changes I made goes when I restart the container. As I'm new to docker I don't know much about it.

My question is that how can I write a docker file so that all libraries like tensorflow theano etc comes installed in it ?

Comment: Check the solution below and don't forget to vote up to encourage better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have done plenty of research on this topic, I will provide a solution. We can achieve this two ways:

- (1) build an image from scratch using "Dockerfile" or "dockerfile". A "dockerfile" allows you to place all the dependencies needed for installation of your packages or libraries.
- **(2)** You can simply run a container of the base-image of the desired OS flavor.Then, go into the container and install all your packages and commit the changes to Docker Hub.
- (1) [Answer] Simply create a Dockerfile and build the image using the desired linux flavor. Check link how to build an image, using a Dockerfile, with all the desired packages and libraries.
- **(2)** **[Answer]**
     Step1: Running a container in detach mode.
  Assign a name to the container you want to run so it is easy to locate and reattach again to it. Learn about the flags I used in the flags link below.

  ```
  docker run --name miniconda2Container -i -t -d conda/miniconda2 /bin/bash
  ```

  [image]
- **(2)** Step2: Use the name of the container you have assigned to run it with the attach command.

  ```
  docker attach miniconda2Container
  ```

  [image]
- **(2)** Step3: Once inside the container proceed to install all your packages.

  ```
  apt-get install <package or library or anything else>
  ```
- **(2)** Up to now, you have done everything properly. When you finished installing everything, detach the container by pressing "Ctrl-p-q" at the same time. You should receive something like the following statement.

  [image]
- **(2)** Then, Commit the changes that you have made inside the container the following way:

  ```
  docker commit -m "This is my update image" miniconda2Container abeltre1/miniconda2:latest
  ```

  [image]

Finally, you can use the [REPOSITORY[:TAG]] to access the image and check that all your packages are installed. In my case the image is: abeltre1/miniconda2:latest.

1. [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)
2. [Run Container
   Flags](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up-rm)
3. [Docker Commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

Comment: Hey **@abeltre1** thanks for your answer commit method worked for me.